# Font size changes only sometimes

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I am having a strange issue. I am trying to edit the font size of one line but it remains fixed.

```
\documentclass [11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\graphicspath{ {./Immagini/} }

\begin{document}

{\fontspec{Bembo Std}\fontsize{18}{25}{\textsc{Working}}}\\
{\fontspec{Bembo Std}\fontsize{80}{100}{Not working}}

\end{document}
```

The first one changes correctly, but the second does not.
The issue appears also when chainging the font.
I am new to latex, so I must have understood something wrong here.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you never selected the font using the new settings. also the text does not go in an argument `\fontsize` applies for the rest of the current group.  but you need `\selectfont` so

```
 {\fontspec{Bembo Std}\fontsize{80}{100}\selectfont Now working}
```